# It's us! / It's we!

Tags: grammar, pronouns, subjects, objects

> It was **him** who meessed up everything.
> It was **he** who messed up
> everything.

> It's **them** who **was** there.
> It's **them** who **were** there.
> It's **they** who **was**  there.
> It's **they** who **were** there.

> It's **me** who **is** sorry.
> It's **me** who **am** sorry.
> It's **I** who **is** sorry.
> It's **I** who **am** sorry.

> A voice at the door: Who's there?
> We/Us: It's **us**!
> We/Us: It's **we**!

> Get him! It's **him**!
> Get him! It's **he**!

Which do we use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pronoun always takes  the verb form that goes with it in a normal sentence (*They were there. I am sorry*).

It's traditionally regarded as correct to use the subject case after *It is.*

> It was he who messed up everything.
>
> It is I who am sorry.

...but in colloquial speech, identifying yourself with *It is I* sounds comically formal and *It's we* downright peculiar! Most people would say *It's me* and *It's him.*

Comment: Thank you! As I understand, sometimes it's better to use object pronoun, and sometimes it is better to use subject pronoun. e.g. It's us! (not It's we), but It's I who am sorry. (not It's me who am sorry)

Comment: Yes, but the less formal version, where the antecedent is in accusative case, requires 3rd person override: "It is me who **is** at fault", where "who" takes on the default 3rd person feature.